# Событие при отправке нового сообщения в телеграм канал Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiohttp

У меня есть бот на aiogram и телеграм канал, в который добавлен этот бот. Как мне реализовать событие, которое вызывается при отправке сообщения в этот телеграм канал? Также, мне нужна проверка на ID этого канала.

Comment: Вам нужен кастомный хендлер?

Comment: Можно и таким способом, рассматриваю любые методы.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы узнать айди канала или группы есть бот **@username_to_id_bot**

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]